# Circular progress bar in AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, diagram

I am developing an AngularJS application and I want to display a circular progress bar like this:
[image]

What should I use for this type of diagram? I tried angular-progress-arc but I can't obtain the incomplete circle from my image.

Comment: @Andrea Can you check [ng-knob](https://github.com/RadMie/ng-knob?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation) It may be able to create such a progress bar easily.

Comment: Yes, it was exactly what I needed.Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material provides a lot of useful UI elements including a circular progress bar. You can set a determinate when values are known. Check out their demos here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressCircular

```
<md-progress-circular md-mode="determinate" value="{{vm.determinateValue}}"></md-progress-circular>
```

Comment: There is also linear progress bar. See docs: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressLinear